# OCIAttrGet/OCI_ATTR_STMT_TYPE return 16 ?

Tags: oracle, oracle-call-interface

OCIAttrGet(stmtp, OCI_HTYPE_STMT, &stmt_type, NULL, OCI_ATTR_STMT_TYPE, errhp);

stmt_type is

OCI only has 9 known SQL statement types.

OCI_STMT_SELECT - SELECT statement

OCI_STMT_UPDATE - UPDATE statement

OCI_STMT_DELETE - DELETE statement

OCI_STMT_INSERT - INSERT statement

OCI_STMT_CREATE - CREATE statement

OCI_STMT_DROP - DROP statement

OCI_STMT_ALTER - ALTER statement

OCI_STMT_BEGIN - BEGIN... (PL/SQL)

OCI_STMT_DECLARE - DECLARE... (PL/SQL)

But, return values is "16"...

If you know what this means, I'll ask for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some values returned from OCI_ATTR_STMT_TYPE are not documented:

- 16 MERGE
- 0 ANALYZE TABLE
- 15 EXPLAIN PLAN FOR
- 17 ROLLBACK
- 21 COMMIT